# Cumulative Normed Histogram

Tags: python, histogram, cumulative-sum

I’ve written a code that gives a Cumulative Normed Histogram.

How can I fix the X axis please?

[image: Cumulative Normed Histogram]

This histogram has the aditional feature of a threshold applied to a second dimension so that information about column "B" can be used as well as column "A".

It also makes it possible to adjust the number "C" that the count is normalised against.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

# Data
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,1,2,3,4,2,1,4],
                     'B': [2,1,2,1,2,3,4,2,1]})

# Cumulative Normed Histogram
bins          = np.arange(0, 5, .2)
df_1['A_Bin'] = pd.cut(df_1['A'], bins=bins)

# Apply a threshold to B
df_2          = df_1[df_1['B'] > 2]

# Get the number of rows
C             = len(df_1.index)

def fun(g):
    try:
        return float(g.shape[0]) / C
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return np.nan

hist       = df_1.groupby('A_Bin').apply(fun)
hist_2     = df_2.groupby('A_Bin').apply(fun)

hist_cum   = hist.cumsum()
hist_2_cum = hist_2.cumsum()

hist_cum.plot()
hist_2_cum.plot()
```

I tried this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xticks((0,2,4,6),('0','2','4','6'))
```

But got this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to get the ticks & put it in a Dataframe like this:

```
    import pandas            as pd
    import numpy             as np

    # Data
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,1,2,3,4,2,1,4],
                         'B': [2,1,2,1,2,3,4,2,1]})

    # Cumulative Normed Histogram
    Min  = 0
    Max  = 6
    Step = .5

    bins          = np.arange(Min, Max, Step)
    df_1['A_Bin'] = pd.cut(df_1['A'], bins=bins)

    # Apply a threshold to B
    df_2          = df_1[df_1['B'] > 2]

    # Get the number of rows
    C             = len(df_1.index)

    def fun(g):
        try:
            return float(g.shape[0]) / C
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return np.nan

    hist                  = df_1.groupby('A_Bin').apply(fun)
    hist_2                = df_2.groupby('A_Bin').apply(fun)

    hist_cum              = hist.cumsum()
    hist_2_cum            = hist_2.cumsum()

    # Put the Histogram in a Dataframe
    df_hist_cum           = hist_cum.to_frame()
    df_hist_2_cum         = hist_2_cum.to_frame()

    # Define the Ticks
    ticks                 = np.arange(Min, (Max-Step), Step)

    df_hist_cum['X']      = ticks
    df_hist_2_cum['X']    = ticks

    df_hist_cum.columns   = ['All', 'A']
    df_hist_2_cum.columns = ['2', 'A']

    ax = df_hist_cum.plot(x='A', y='All')
    df_hist_2_cum.plot(x='A', y='2', ax=ax)
```

[image]